# How to convert a Restpage to a specific object type in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am using the following to return a page of objects from my backend service:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"pageable"})
class RestPage<Role> extends PageImpl<Role> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestPage.class);

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public RestPage(@JsonProperty("content") List<Role> content,
                    @JsonProperty("number") int page,
                    @JsonProperty("size") int size,
                    @JsonProperty("totalElements") long total,
                    @JsonProperty("numberOfElements") int numberOfElements,
                    @JsonProperty("pageNumber") int pageNumber
    ) {
        super(content, PageRequest.of(page, size), total);
    }

    public RestPage(Page<Role> page) {
        super(page.getContent(), page.getPageable(), page.getTotalElements());
        LOG.info("page.content: {}", page.getContent());
    }

    

}
```

When I fetch the page from the following http requests and attempt to go thru the stream with list using following code:

```
  EntityExchangeResult<RestPage> entityExchangeResult = webTestClient.get().uri("/roles/"+organizationId)
                .headers(addJwt(jwt)).exchange().expectStatus().isOk().expectBody(RestPage.class)
                .returnResult();

       
        LOG.info("roles found: {}", entityExchangeResult.getResponseBody().getContent());
        List<Role> list = entityExchangeResult.getResponseBody().getContent();
        List<String> listOfNames = list.stream().map(Role::getName).collect(toList());
```

I get the following error on the `map()` function line:

```
class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class my.package.repo.entity.Role
```

Is there a way to put a ObjectMapper call in the `RestPage` to convert to the Object type I want?  I would like to get my specific type instead of a LinkedHashMap that I am seeing currently.